# Python: ascii codec u'\xe8 when writing list of lists

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I am trying to write to file a list of lists, when I try to convert my list of lists to string i get an encoding error.

value contains a list of list like the following:

```
[[fsdé,fsdqè,fdsq],[foo1,foo2,foo3]]
```

Here is my code:

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in value))
```

and here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "package_list_script.py", line 23, in craft_json

    f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in value))

  File "package_list_script.py", line 23, in <genexpr>

    f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in value))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

*SOLUTION*

```
with io.open("somefile.txt", "w") as fout: fout.write(u"\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)) for l in value))
```

using Python 3 module and specifying "u" before the string ! AMEN

Comment: try `f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map(str.encode('utf-8'),l)) for l in value))`.

Comment: Actually i get an error saying: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Use `utf-8` encoding - `str.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @Rémi Could you tell us what `value` contains? You could also try just this - `f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map(str,l)))`

Comment: a list of list like the following: [[foo1,foo2,foo3],[fdsfdsqq,fdfdssq,fdsqfsdq]]

Comment: but it contains characters like the following: é, è, ê

Comment: @KartikKannapur i get the same error

Comment: Yes, utf-8 would encode all possible characters. For more info on utf-8 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 Is the input text in a language other than English?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: French, but we use the same character excpet we have accents (é,à,é,ê)

Comment: How about `map(unicode, alist)` instead of `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3 will do this for you.

In Python 2, you can use Python 3's io module like so:

```
with io.open("somefile.txt", "w") as fout: fout.write(u"\N{EURO SIGN}")
```

You can specify `encoding=...` explicitly to `io.open` or as I did here, I relied on default, which is `locale.getpreferredencoding()`

Comment: this seems good, but i still get the same error, i just dont understand where is this coming from !

Comment: IT WORKED ! i edited my first post thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you need to join *strings containing accented characters* and then write them to files. As you try to convert them using str and as you get an `UnicodeEncodeError` I assume that l is an list of list of `unicode`.

You can simply try to process everything in unicode:

```
f.write((u"\n".join(u"\t".join(l) for l in value)).encode(encoding))
```

where encoding could be `latin1`, `utf8`, `cp1252` or whatever is the encoding that you want to use for your file.

Alternatively, you can *encode* the individual strings:

```
f.write("\n".join("\t".join(map((lambda x: x.encode('utf8')), l)) for l in value))
```

Comment: I tried both method but i still get issues, the second method seems the most viable to me, but i get an error saying: "list" object has not attribute 'encorde'